# how i find relief from this error the error is undefined index: host in C:\wamp\www\serp-tracker\get_serps.php on line 42

Tags: php

i'm getting output from this code but the server giving me an error

> Notice: Undefined index: host in
>   "C:\wamp\www\serp-tracker\get_serps.php on line 42"

any body can help me to provide me solution about this error

```
<div class="form-group" <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="host" <?php if($_GET["host"]!=""){ echo 'value="'.$_GET["host"].'"';}else{ echo 'value="'.$myhost.'"'; }?> name="host">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `empty()` to check if it is available. Try with -

```
if(!empty($_GET["host"]))
```

`if($_GET["host"]!="")` will generate the error if `host` is not present.

Comment: please provide any other solution sir

Comment: tank u its i found exactly what i need